# Is the tense in the main clause correct, when both the actions in the clauses are taking place at the same time?

Tags: tense, clauses, grammatical-number

> Seeing the little girl's performance, the audience were enthralled.

When both actions in the participle clause and main clause are taking place at the same time, is the tense in the main clause correct in this sentence?

**Edit Note:**

@VarunKN gave a good answer about the noun *audience* being used with singular or plural verb agreement. However, my main question is:

-The participial clause is in active voice and the main clause is in passive voice so do we need to change the voice in the main clause. If so, what would be the change?

In my example sentence, the audience is doing the  seeing in the participial clause, but the girl is doing the enthralling in the main clause.

Comment: You are free to use 'was' or 'were'. The word 'audience' can take both - 'is' and 'are'.

Comment: A note on "audience": [Is “audience” singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58692/11482)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good observation. I recently came across an article on this. [Go through it](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm). Certain collective nouns can be followed by either a singular or plural verb based on how the *'collective noun'*, like *family* or *audience*, is  viewed by the subject. In most cases, people tend to use *'the audience **was**...'*, but that doesn't mean *'the audience **is**...'* is wrong. You can view a few examples [here](http://www.grammaring.com/nouns-with-a-singular-form-and-a-singular-or-plural-meaning-collective-nouns). A discussion was also held on a forum, which can be viewed by clicking [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-to-use-audience-in-plural-form.2551471/).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information @ Varun KN.  But my question is the participial clause is in active voice and the main clause is in passive voice so do we need to change the voice in the main clause. If so, what would be the change?